# Adjust the vertical position of margin notes to the baseline of the body text

Tags: marginnote

I want the first line of my margin notes—which are set in `\small` size—to be at the height of the baseline of the body text, like this:

[image]

My problem is that using something simple like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand{\marginfont}{\small}
\begin{document}
What can I do to align the first line of the marginnote?\marginnote{D-D-D-Drop the baseline!}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: @TonioElGringo's answer works as good as @Steven B. Segletes's, with the difference Steven's `\mynote` is justified. Thank you both, and @karlkoeller too, of course. You're great! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your own with the `tabto` package.  EDITED to flip `\mynote` margin on every page.  You can choose to fix the `\mynote` in a single margin (left or right) by eliminating the `\AddEverypageHook` and setting `\pagesense` to `R` or `L` as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabto,everypage}
\def\pagesense{R}
\AddEverypageHook{\if R\pagesense\gdef\pagesense{L}\else\gdef\pagesense{R}\fi}
\renewcommand{\marginfont}{\small}
\newcommand\mynote[1]{%
  \if R\pagesense%
    \tabto*{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax}%
  \else%
    \tabto*{\dimexpr-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth\relax}%
  \fi%
  \smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\small#1}}%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
  {}%
}
\textwidth=3.9in
\begin{document}
Original marginnote\par
What can I do to align the first line of the marginnote?\marginnote{D-D-D-Drop the baseline!} Here I continue the text.
\vspace{.2in}

Revised mynote\par
What can I do to align the first line of the marginnote?\mynote{D-D-D-Drop the baseline!} Here I continue the text.

\lipsum[1-5]

Another test.\mynote{I should be to the left}

\lipsum[6-10]

Last test.\mynote{I'm back on the right}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ArchStanton  Thanks.  And the nice thing with `\mynote` is that you can tailor the definition to your need, for example, replacing `\small` with `\small\sffamily\raggedright`, etc.

Comment: There's another problem: the notes now are always set in the right margin, instead of the outer margin. Can you correct this? I don't understand your code enough to tweak it with any consciousness of what I'm doing...

Comment: @ArchStanton The line `\tabto*{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax}` says to always move to the x-location (relative to the left margin) of `\textwidth` plus `\marginparsep`.  What you need is to make this `tabto*` dependent on the page number.  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @ArchStanton  Please see revision.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\marginnotevadjust` to adjust this.

```
\renewcommand{\marginnotevadjust}{0.157ex}
```

It seems to me that the value of `0.157ex` is correct but my eyes are not so good, so modify the value if you notice that it's wrong.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand{\marginfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\marginnotevadjust}{0.157ex}
\begin{document}
What the \ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots can I do to align the first line of the marginnote?\marginnote{D-D-D-Drop the baseline!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it only for one instance, instead of redefining `\marginnotevadjust` globally, you can use the optional argument of `\marginnote` as in

```
\marginnote{D-D-D-Drop the baseline!}[0.157ex]
```

Comment: Thank you Karl. I thought there was a more precise way than adjusting the height by eye, though.

Comment: @ArchStanton You're welcome. I thought the right one was `1pt` (the difference between `\baselineskip` with `\normalfont` and `\small`) but I was wrong...

Comment: I too have tried with 1 point and 10.00002-9.24994 pt (the difference between normal and small size according to the Wikibook), but that was wrong too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick and dirty hack to get the expected result: just replace the `\marginfont` definition with this one:

```
\renewcommand{\marginfont}{\noindent\rule{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}\tiny}
```

It will ensure the first line of the margin note has the same height as the one in the text, thus will be aligned.

Comment: Can you tell me how this works? It doesn't seem to be "by eye", but it's weirdly simple :-)

Comment: @ArchStanton `\rule{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}` is like `strut`, so the line has the same height as the text, but with a depth of `0pt` instead of `0.3\baselineskip` (so it doesn't mess with the next line).

Comment: So basically by default we have `\rule[0.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}` and you're removing the `0.3\baselineskip` depth to lay the text on the baseline?

Comment: No, basically `0.7\baselineskip` is the height of a line in the text, and this code is juste adding an invisible character with that height to the first line of the note, so the line has the same height as the text. This works because the top of the note is aligned with the top of the text line.